# Python confluent_kafka: consume(0) cannot trigger callbacks

Tags: python, c, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, librdkafka

I am using [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) and [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka).

But I think, [confluent_kafka.Consumer.consume(0)](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/#confluent_kafka.Consumer.consume) cannot trigger stats_cb.

[Consumer_consume(0)](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/confluent_kafka/src/Consumer.c#L911) => [rd_kafka_consume_batch_queue](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/133bfb8336fba80a881fb5d2f7cc8e7268c9fec4/src/rdkafka.c#L2689)
=> [rd_kafka_q_serve_rkmessages](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/b50e247b77864c595569f7f7e9ec8dde63258210/src/rdkafka_queue.c#L519)

In, `rd_kafka_poll_cb` is called in the `while (cnt < rkmessages_size) loop`. If `rkmessages_size` is 0, it is not called.

In this case, `rk_rep` may become larger and larger.

How to trigger stats_cb in `Consumer_consume(0)`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are served from `rd_kafka_q_serve_rkmessages()`:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/b50e247b77864c595569f7f7e9ec8dde63258210/src/rdkafka_queue.c#L574

If you're not seeing your stats_cb being triggered, make sure that `statistics.interval.ms` is set to a non-zero value.